# CreateDC(), CreateCompatibleDC() or similar for a memory DC without a desktop

Tags: winapi, gdi

I'd like to create a [Memory Device Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/memory-device-contexts) that I can use to invoke GDI functions, paint windows (using `WM_PRINTCLIENT`) etc. from a program that doesn't have access to the desktop (e.g. from a windows service without desktop permissions or a locked screen).

Normally, I'd use `CreateCompatibleDC()`, but it requires a source hDC to copy from, so this function is not available if the calling program doesn't have a desktop. Also `CreateDC("DISPLAY",...)` will fail here for the same reason.

What I need is a *software* Device Context capable of running any normal DC calls, but tied to a specific BITMAP that I can use to get the results from.

Is there a way to solve this? Perhaps borrowing from a printer driver? (I don't need high performance).

I need this to work on Windows Server 2019, and I can use C#, C++, etc.

Comment: `CreateCompatibleDC(nullptr)` doesn't work?

Comment: @JonathanPotter not across session boundaries, no

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think I need to go across session boundaries. I want to interact with a program that is in the same session as mine; they're both in the same session _without a real desktop_ (think Docker).

Comment: @JonathanPotter It turns out that `CreateCompatibleDC(nullptr)` _does_ work, at least in my case. ‍♂️ Thank you. Can you write that as an answer so I can close my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateCompatibleDC(nullptr)` will work in this instance.